# Why once changed select value though javascript button, I can´t choose select value through html?

Tags: javascript, html, select

I noticed this strange thing (at least for newbie like me). I attach JSfiddle script:
https://jsfiddle.net/kubaSpolsky/5dn67frg/1/

Steps: 
1) choose one of the values 
2) click on Display 
3) Reset 
4) Select once again 
5) Display ... this time appears "undifined"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <select id="test" name="" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose...</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="boo">boo</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btn_1">Display</button>
    <button id="btn_2">Reset</button>
    <p id="result"></p>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    let test = document.getElementById("test");
    let btnDisplay = document.getElementById("btn_1");
    let btnReset = document.getElementById("btn_2");
    let p = document.getElementById("result");

    btnDisplay.onclick = function(){
        console.log(test.value)
        p.innerHTML = test.value;
    }
    btnReset.onclick = function(){
        test = document.getElementById("test").value = "0";
    }
</script>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reassigning the value of `test` to something other than the select box on reset.

```
       test = document.getElementById("test").value = "0";
```

simply get rid of the reassignment:

```
      document.getElementById("test").value = "0";
```

---

### Example:

```js
    let test = document.getElementById("test");
    let btnDisplay = document.getElementById("btn_1");
    let btnReset = document.getElementById("btn_2");
    let p = document.getElementById("result");

    btnDisplay.onclick = function(){
        console.log(test.value)
        p.innerHTML = test.value;
    }
    btnReset.onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("test").value = "0";
    }
```

```html
   <select id="test" name="" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Choose...</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="boo">boo</option>
    </select>

    <button id="btn_1">Display</button>
    <button id="btn_2">Reset</button>
    <p id="result"></p>
```